# Conditioned vector creation based on another vector

Tags: r, vector

I'm a new user in R. Considering the following vector `example <- c (15 1 1 1 7 8 8 9 5 9 5)`, I would like to create two additional vectors, the first with only the repeated numbers and the second with numbers that are not repeated, something like:

`example1 <- c (15, 7)`

`example2 <- c (1, 8, 9, 5)`

Thank you for your support.

Answer (score 2):

Using `example` shown reproducibly in the Note at the end `dups` is formed from the duplicated elements and `singles` is the rest,  This always gives two vectors (one will be zero length if there are no duplicates of if there are no singles) and it uses the numeric values directly without converting them to character.

```
dups <- unique(example[duplicated(example)])
singles <- setdiff(example, dups)

dups
## [1] 1 8 9 5

singles
## [1] 15  7
```

### Note

The input shown in the question was not valid R syntax so we provide the input reproducibly here:

```
example <- scan(text = "15 1 1 1 7 8 8 9 5 9 5", quiet = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thank you very much @G. Grothendieck, it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

You can count the appereances of the values using `table`:

```
example <- c(15,1,1,1,7,8,8,9,5,9,5)
tt <- table(example)
```

The names of the table are the counted values, so you can write:

```
repeatedValues <- as.numeric(names(tt)[tt>1])
uniqueValues <- as.numeric(names(tt))[tt==1]
```

Comment: Thanks @Jonas. Your answer is very intuitive, it worked well.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a one-liner using `rle` that puts the resultant vectors in a list:

```r
split(rle(sort(example))$values, rle(sort(example))$lengths < 2)
#> $`FALSE`
#> [1] 1 5 8 9

#> $`TRUE`
#> [1]  7 15
```

Comment: The list will have one component if there are no dups or no singles as opposed to two components with one empty.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck yes, I know. Using it in production code would require an extra line as an existential check. I think your answer is the best of the three and have upvoted, but I thought I would illustrate a different approach to using `table` and unique-duplicate.

Comment: @Nuñes it is run-length encoding. It converts a vector into a list of two shorter vectors - one giving the values, another the length of the values. If you sort the vector first it will act a bit like `table`, except the values don't get converted to characters. `rle` is a useful trick to have up your sleeve.

Comment: Excellent @Allan Cameron, it was very clear. It really is a very useful function, especially when we want a numerical output. Thank you.